# rxjs do in Effects

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am learning angular and I'm in using of `Effects`. I have a logout code and working fine. But my problem is when using code below it's not navigating.

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
authLogOut = this.actions$
    .pipe(ofType(AuthActions.LOGOUT))
    .pipe(tap(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
    }))
```

**AuthActions.ts**

```
export const TRY_SIGNIN = 'TRY_SIGNIN';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';
export class Logout implements Action {
     readonly type = LOGOUT;
}
export class TrySignin implements Action {
    readonly type = TRY_SIGNIN;
   constructor(public payload: { username: string, password: string }) {

  }
}
export type AuthActions =  Logout | Signin
```

But when I signin the navigations works fine.

```
@Effect()
authSignin = this.actions$
    .pipe(ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNIN))
    .pipe(map((action: AuthActions.TrySignin) => {
        return action.payload;
    }))
    .pipe(switchMap((authData: { username: string, password: string }) => {
        return from(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            authData.username, authData.password));
    }))
    .pipe(switchMap(() => {
        return from(firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken())
    }))
    .pipe(mergeMap((token: string) => {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
        return [
            {
                type: AuthActions.SIGNIN
            },
            {
                type: AuthActions.SET_TOKEN,
                payload: token
            }
        ]
    }))
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second pipe.

```
.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.LOGOUT),
    tap(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After how many hours of looking for my problem. I solve it by checking my routing. I accidentally put a guard in my router that pointing to that URL.